# Как использовать MySQL в UWP приложении

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Есть маленькое приложение UWP, которое сохраняет и считывает информацию из базы данных MySQL. Библиотека подключена из NuGet. При тестировании все работает отлично. Но при компиляции выходят подобные предупреждения. После установки приложения связи с базой данных нет. Правильно я понимаю, что [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) нужно куда-то добавить? Не знаю куда.

> MCG : warning MCG0007: Неразрешенный метод P/Invoke
>   "secur32!AcquireCredentialsHandle" для метода "System.Int32
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlWindowsAuthenticationPlugin.AcquireCredentialsHandle(System.String,
>   System.String, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr,
>   System.Int32, System.IntPtr,
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.SECURITY_HANDLE,
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.SECURITY_INTEGER)".
>
> Вызов этого метода приведет к исключению во время выполнения. Убедитесь, что
>   P/Invoke указывает на API Windows, разрешенный в приложениях UWP, или
>   на библиотеку DLL в машинном коде, которая является частью пакета.
>   Если по какой-то причине P/Invoke не отвечает этим условиям,
>   используйте [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true), чтобы показать, что вы
>   понимаете последствия использования API, не относящихся к UWP.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131113/how-to-use-mysql-with-windows-10-uwp-app)

Соединение с базой данных (еще) не работает официальным MySQL Connector (из-за некоторых неподдерживаемых ссылок), но есть альтернативы. Наиболее перспективными являются те, которые поддерживают .NET Standard. Например, проект [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) предлагает интерфейс, очень похожий на официальный connector . Он все еще находится в бета-версии, но регулярно обновляется и активно развивается.

Answer (score 0):

Приложения UWP могут использовать неуправляемые функции только из набора [разрешенных функций Windows API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps). Возможно, установка ExactSpelling в объявлении P/Invoke позволит вызывать любые функции в режиме разработчика, но при публикации в магазин приложение все равно не пройдет сертификацию. В данном случае код библиотеки MySqlClient вызывает функцию [AcquireCredentialsHandle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acquirecredentialshandlea), которая не входит в список разрешенных API.

Раз у вас код работает, то вы, видимо, просто не используете функционал, связанный с Windows-авторизацией, и не сталкиваетесь с этой проблемой из-за этой функции. MySQL в принципе поддерживается в UWP, но, судя по [этой статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/data-access/mysql-databases), минимальная версия Windows должна быть 16299.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Вы мне помогли найти проблемы. Если Вам интересно, ознакомьтесь с решением проблемы.